# using ANOVA test for comparing multiple samples

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a matrix,which each of columns is the algorithm output for some tries.

I want to compare the mean of each algorithms with all others.

how can i do this with matlab?

Comment: Do you have the Statistics Toolbox?

Comment: Exactly what comparison do you want to do?

Comment: yes i have the matlab toolbox

Comment: i have run multiple evolutionary algorithms

than i want to compare with each other

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the functions and examples that the Statistics Toolbox has for [ANOVA](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/analysis-of-variance-anova-1.html)?